# How to parse a sentence with verb 'bring'

Tags: construction

> “He brought the umbrella swishing down through the air to point at
>   Dudley.”
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I guess the sentence could be parsed as below:
[He] [brought] [A: the umbrella swishing down through the air] [B: to point at Dudley.]
(A: direct object of brought, B: result or aim of the previous saying.)
But, I cannot have confidence with the parsing. Could you show me how to see the construction?

Comment: _Bring_ is a causative of _come_ (just as _take_ is a causative of _go_), so it means _He caused the umbrella to come swishing down_. The construction is the same as in _go swimming_ or _take her dancing_ -- a serial verb of motion followed by a gerund clause, in either A or B configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is right in that A is not a noun phrase. That is, "a car going down the road" is "a car that is going down the road," which is a noun phrase.

Instead, there is the gerund phrase "swishing down through the air," which is the object complement, like the verb "eat" in the sentence "he made her eat."

Examples of complements:

Subject complement: the "red" in "she is red."
Object complement: the red in "I dyed the shirts red."